# Which parts panel contains control surfaces?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I'm just trying to make a plane in sandbox mode, and I can't find control surfaces. Thanks!

Comment: If you're playing in Career or Science mode, have you unlocked any of the science groups containing control surfaces yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control surfaces from previous versions got redesigned and are now named Elevon 1 to Elevon 5. Most parts named "Winglet" and "Canard" can also work as control surfaces.

When the part selector is in basic mode, you find them in the "Aerodynamics" section.

When you set the part selector in "Advanced" mode (icon in the upper left corner) you can also "filter by module" where you find the "control surfaces" group as the third from the top:

[image]